# Python Assigning value from one variable to another

Tags: python, arrays, variables

I am trying to implement some sort of local search. For this I have two arrays, which represent a list, that I am trying to optimize. 
So I have one array as the current best array and the one I am currently analyzing.

At the beginning I am shuffling the array and set the current best array to the shuffled array.

```
random.shuffle(self.matchOrder)
self.bestMatchOrder = self.matchOrder
```

Then I am swapping a random neighboured pair in the array. 
Now the problem I have is that when I am swapping the values in `self.matchOrder`, the values in `self.bestMatchOrder` get swapped.

```
a = self.matchOrder[index]
self.matchOrder[index] = self.matchOrder[index + 1]
self.matchOrder[index + 1] = a
```

"index" is given to the function as a parameter, it is just randomly generated number.

I guess I did something wrong assigning the variables, but I can't figure out what. So what can I do to only assign the value of the array to the other array and not make it apply the same changes to it, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `self.bestMatchOrder = self.matchOrder` Then Python doesn't allocates a new memory location to `self.bestMatchOrder` instead both are pointing to the same memory location. And knowing the fact that the lists are **mutable** data type, Hence any changes made in the `self.matchOrder` would get reflected in the `self.bestMatchOrder`.

```
import copy

self.bestMatchOrder = copy.deepcopy(self.matchOrder)
```

However if you are using linear lists or simple lists the you can also use `self.bestMatchOrder = self.matchOrder[:]` But if yo are using nested lists then `deepcopy()` is the correct choice.

Comment: Thanks for this very fast answer :)
I already thought of something like this. What gets me confused, why do I make bestMatchOrder still pointing to a different memory location after I initialized it in the Object initialization?

Comment: It Works, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy a list, you can use slice operation:

```
list_a = [1, 2, 3]
list_b = list_a[:]
list_a = [0, 0, 42]
print list_a  # returns [0, 0, 42]
print list_b  # returns [1, 2, 3], i.e. copied values
```

But if you have more complex structures, you should use `deepcopy`, as @anmol_uppal advised above.